# Why is Play Store still asking for all app permissions on install on Android Marshmallow?

Tags: google-play-store, permissions, 6.0-marshmallow

From everything I've read, when installing a new app from the Play Store under Marshmallow, it is supposed to just install with no permission questions (e.g. [Slash Gear article](http://www.slashgear.com/android-6-0-apps-can-ask-permissions-only-when-needed-28399753/)). The app is then supposed to ask for each permission it needs as you run it.

This is not happening on my Nexus 5 which I updated via OTA to 6.0 earlier this week. When clicking install in the Play Store, still getting the massive list of permissions along with an Accept button. Is there a setting that is needed to make this work as expected?

Comment: See if this helps. Ars Technica noted [here](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/10/android-6-0-marshmallow-thoroughly-reviewed/5/): "*Apps that target the new SDK and are installed on a 6.0 device won't ask for any permissions at install time. That's right—the "install" button in the Play Store will actually install the app now.*" It also noted "*Old apps that don't target the Android M SDK will still show a big list of permissions at install time.*" My question: which app(s) did you try to install and is/are it/they updated for Android 6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the app has to be made with API 23 (aka Marshmallow's API) *and* the user has to be on 6.0 Marshmallow or higher for what you want to take effect. However, you can still go into **Settings - Apps** and change each app's permissions individually, or go into **Advanced** under *Apps* (the gear icon) and change them by category.

Source: [Android Developers - Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Unfortunate that it works this way, as some apps I'd like to install but would prefer not to give even momentary access to things like contacts.  Guess I'll continue to defer installing those apps until they get upgraded to 23.