# Play Store is not giving me app permissions and asking if I accept anymore

Tags: google-play-store, 6.0-marshmallow, permissions

Recently I have a Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android Marshmallow. On my previous device, when I wanted to download an app in the Play Store, it would show all permissions for me to accept it. Now, all of a sudden, when I go to download an app, it just downloads without giving me the permissions or asking if I accept them.

I am not sure what happened, but I'm worried as some things, like Facebook for example, ask for way too many permissions that are not even necessary.

Why is the Play Store not giving me app permissions and asking if I accept anymore?

Comment: Did you update to Marshmallow? Related: [Why is Play Store still asking for all app permissions on install on Android Marshmallow?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/126153)

Comment: This should clear all doubts: [Understanding App Permissions](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-App-Permissions#backwards-compatibility)

Answer (score 3):

In Android 6.0 permissions have changed from older "all or nothing" approach (where play store prompted you to accept all permissions an app is asking for) to a more granular structure, where the prompt for each permission (e.g. Camera, Contacts, Phone, etc.) appears the first time an app requests it.  New or updated apps that were designed with this feature in mind will no longer ask for permissions when you install them.

Keep in mind that each app needs to be modified by developers to support this new functionality.  Older apps that have not been changed will still prompt you at install time, same as before.

Users are given even more control in the Settings app where they can revoke or grant these permissions as they see fit.  You can revoke permissions for older apps, but those may crash or become unstable.

More detailed explanation [here](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-take-advantage-new-app-permissions-marshmallow).